# Downloading a zip file from console and inserting into a directory

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have a backup in a zip file which I need to download and save in a folder in my console. I use the DigitalOcean cloud and Ubuntu 18.04. The backup zip file is located both on my desktop and in the Google Drive. I'm trying to figure a way to download this zip file into one of the directories in the console. Which command can I use? What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **wget**, wget your_url -O your outputFileName, if it use https add --no-check-certificate

`wget "https://example.com/example.zip" --no-check-certificate -O /path/new_file_name.zip`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

If you have zip file in your local computer and you want it's contents to be in the cloud, you probably want to upload it, not download.

If you use Ubuntu locally (it's not clear if it's on your DigitalOcean instance or in your PC), you can use `scp` command, which is "copy via SSH".

You can see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232947/29627) for an example how to copy the whole folder – it might be easier to extract the zip in your local computer. Keep in mind that you must run this in your local command line, not in DigitalOcean.

Other way would be to make a sharable link in your Google Drive and use curl to download the file.

```
curl "https://drive.google.com/open?id=abc" > backup.zip
unzip backup.zip
```